# Сохранение стиля в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Выбираю стиль: Опции -> Определение стилей -> Выбираю стиль
Сохраняю. При следующем открытии документа стиль не сохранен

Comment: Какая версия `Notepad++` используется и как сохраняете, нажимаете **Ok**?

Comment: версия 7.1; Сохраняю изменения через ок